# Fill not applying to SVG using vivus.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, vivus

Hey guys i have the following SVG drawing animation using vivus.js **[SEE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/yqu7tcty/)**, the svg is below:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .st0 {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #020000;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  }

</style>

<path id="XMLID_3_" class="st0" d="M-0.5,3.5H19c0,0,1.5-0.1,1.5,1.6V77c0,0,1,1.1,2,0V4c0,0,0-1.5,1.4-1.3l20.4,0c0,0,8,0.1,12,8.7
                S54.9,31.6,42,32.9l0.1,2.8c0,0,20.8,0.5,20.1,19.8c0,0-0.1,16.5-19.6,19.5v3c0,0,14.5-0.3,19-10.4c0,0,13-22.6-10-32.9V34
                c0,0,9.8-5.3,9.1-15.6c0,0,0.5-8.8-7.4-15l8.1-0.1l0.4,38L62,75.9c0,0,1.6,1.2,3.2-0.1s0-73.3,0-73.3h22.3V76c0,0,3.1,2.1,4.3-0.1
                s0-73.4,0-73.4H104c0,0,9.5,1.8,9.5,11.1V76c0,0,1.6,2.1,3.5,0s0-66.1,0-66.1s-2.5-9.4-16-9.4H-0.5V3.5z" />
```

I am using the following JS to animate the svg:

```
new Vivus('svglogo', {duration: 200} , function() {
    $('#svglogo st0').attr({'fill' : '#020000'})
});
```

Now after the drawing is complete i would like to add the fill to the logo and so i have the following in the callback function:

```
$('#svglogo st0').attr({'fill' : '#020000'})
```

But this really does't seem to work, can somebody tell me what am i doing wrong here ? why is the fill not applying ? I'd really like to apply the fill once the drawing animation is complete .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fill property set by CSS style overrules the fill attribute.  You should be using

```
$('#svglogo st0').css({'fill' : '#020000'})
```